# git rebase and remote push

Tags: git, branch

I'm new to git and I made a boo boo.  I started a new branch (poly_attr), checked it out, made some commits.  While I was still in that branch I worked on a couple other things that should've gone to a different branch.  So I committed everything that should be in poly_attr, then created and checked out a new branch (issue1), committed changes, and pushed both branches.  Guess what I forgot to do?  Check out the master before creating issue1.  So my issue1 branch went off of poly_attr.  Ok, easy fix, I think, check out master and rebase issue1 to master.  Nope, now I have an issue1 branch off of poly_attr (remote), and one off master (local).
How can I get the issue1 branch off of poly_attr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To paraphrase, you started with this:

```
... - M5 - M6               <-- master, origin/master
```

That is, there were some series of commits (which I've numbered, `Mn`).  You made a new branch name `poly_attr` pointing to the same commit as the tip of `master` and made more commits, which I'll label `Pn`:

```
... - M5 - M6                   <-- master, origin/master
             \
              P0 - P1           <-- poly_attr
```

Then you made a new branch `issue1` starting at the end of `poly_attr` (not where you had intended to start), and made more commits:

```
... - M5 - M6                   <-- master, origin/master
             \
              P0 - P1           <-- poly_attr
                     \
                      I0 - I1   <-- issue1
```

Then you did a `git push` that pushed both `poly_attr` and `issue1` to your remote (the second goof).

The remote now has commits `I0` and `I1` (with the same branch labels on the remote as you have on your local), and you can't erase them from there unless you can log in there and do stuff including `git gc`.  Worse, assuming the repo on `origin` is shared, *other people* may have them by now.  This in turn means, how you fix this depends on how sure you are no one else has them, how much influence you have over anyone who *does* have them, and/or how desperate you are to have the ultimate branch history "look simple".

It's easy, in your own repo, to run `git rebase -i master issue1` and choose to carry over only commits `I0` and `I1`, or even `git rebase --onto master poly_attr issue1` to carry over `I0` and `I1` without having to edit the interactive rebase stuff.  In either case your end result is:

```
... - M5 - M6                   <-- master, origin/master
            |\
            | P0 - P1           <-- poly_attr, origin/poly_attr
            |        \
            |         I0 - I1   <-- origin/issue1
             \
              I0' - I1'         <-- issue1
```

Note that the `I` chain of commits are *still there*, and the remaining label they have is the "remote branch" `origin/issue1`.

If you're **sure** no one else has grabbed `issue1` from the remote, and if you have sufficient permission, you can `git push -f origin issue1:issue1` after doing your rebase.  That will send over the new commits `I0'` and `I1'` and make the remote move his `issue1` label to point to `I1'`, the tip of your new `issue1` branch.  The old commits (`I0` and `I1`) will still be around for a while, but no one will see them, they won't be in the way, and eventually they'll be garbage-collected:

```
... - M5 - M6                   <-- master, origin/master
            |\
            | P0 - P1           <-- poly_attr, origin/poly_attr
            |        \
            |         I0 - I1       [invisible and eventually gc'd]
             \
              I0' - I1'         <-- issue1, origin/issue1
```

Even if others *have* grabbed it, if you have sufficient permission and power, you can perhaps force them to take your change.  ("Sorry guys, if you cloned and got issue1, please note I've forcibly rebased it and you'll have to figure out how to fix any stuff you did that depended on it.")

If you're not sure or don't have permission or whatever, you will have to live with something messier.  Instead of making new commits (the `In'` ones), you will simply have to add, on to the end of the `issue1` chain, commits that undo the effect of each `Pn` commit.  You can do that fairly simply, starting with the original (non-rebased) chain:

```
... - M5 - M6                   <-- master, origin/master
             \
              P0 - P1           <-- poly_attr
                     \
                      I0 - I1   <-- issue1
```

Just use `git revert` to apply the inverse of changes made in the `P` series:

```
$ git checkout issue1
$ git revert master..poly_attr
```

This gives you the new chain:

```
... - M5 - M6                   <-- master, origin/master
             \
              P0 - P1           <-- poly_attr
                     \
                      I0 - I1 - RP1 - RP0   <-- issue1
```

where `RP1` is a commit that reverts (reverses) `P1`, and `RP0` is a commit that reverts `P0`.  If you added a file in `P1`, it gets removed in `RP1`.  If you deleted a line of code in `P0`, it gets put back in `RP0`.  This means that the end result, the *files* you get when checking out `RP0`, look the same as if you had made the changes in `I0` and `I1` on top of the commit `M6`.  The history, of course, looks quite different, and it's a good idea to explain (in the revert commits) why this happened.  But the end result is the same, and you are only adding new commits on to the end of the `In` chain, which means other people who have the commits can pick up the new stuff with little fuss.

Comment: Wow, torek!  That is the best and most descriptive answer I think I've seen.  Thank you so much.  You got it exactly right.  Luckily I'm not worried about anyone else pulling down the branches as yet, which is I why I just went ahead and pushed the changes without a thorough look over.  I think I've got it under control now.  Thanks again.